# php - email from hotmail accounts not received by easyspace mail account

Tags: php, email

I use the mail() function to email customer completed forms to my easyspace account. However any forms that have a hotmail from email address specified are unreceived. They are not in my spam folder either. If i send an email direct from a hotmail account this doesn't happen. Any ideas why this would be happening?

Comment: Please show the code you are using to send the mail.

Answer (score 1):

Never ever use a `from` address that differs from the domain your site is running on. You can put into `reply-to` anything you want (including hotmail addresses) but `from` must contain a legit mail address.